# xcode - tableview where each row repeats the viewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, tableview

How to have multiple items to be present in each cell of a single column tableview

e.g. multiple texts , multiple buttons etc.

Can i design a view controller with my desired cell and have the
   tableview repeat this viewcontroller format on every row but with
   different values for texts and different links for buttons all coming
   from sqlite database.

has anyone implemented this who can guide me ?

Comment: made custom UITableViewCell

Comment: Check [here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/customizing-uitableview-cell/) for custom UITableviewCell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of custom tablecell to achieve this.UIviewControllers purpose is different.

[A startup and must read guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html)